# Want to Post pure XML to an asmx webmethod without Soap envelope

Tags: xml, web-services, httprequest

I am building an ASMX web service that will support both soap and also an httpRequest with pure xml with  no soap envelope. 
I am having no problem creating a web method that uses soap, but, i am having trouble figuring out how to create a web method that will accept just pure xml as a string.
I need this because I have two sources of sales leads one that uses soap and the other uses HttpRequests with plain xml no soap envelope. I would like the web service to handle both of these.

Comment: ASMX is a legacy technology, and should not be used for new development. WCF or ASP.NET Web API should be used for all new development of web service clients and servers. One hint: Microsoft has retired the [ASMX Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/asmxandxml/threads) on MSDN.

Comment: I should have mentioned that this web service is running under IIS 7.5

Comment: Doesn't matter which IIS version you're using. ASMX can't easily be used to expose the same service on multiple endpoints. This is trivial with WCF.